# is my induction proof that $n!\gt n^2$ sufficient?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, induction

question;

*prove  that  $\forall\ n\ge4, n\in \mathbb{Z},  \ n!\gt n^2$.*

my work;

*let $n=4$ then  $4!=24 \gt 4^2=16.$ true.*  now assume $n! \gt n^2$ is true for all $n\le k$

so now assume $k! \gt k^2$, so that the induction step is as follows,

$(k+1)!=(k+1)k! \gt k^2(k+1)=k^3+k^2 \gt k^2+2k+1=(k+1)^2$

which now shows that $n! \gt n^2$ holds for $(n+1)$ and is thus true for $n\ge 4$.

or do I have show that $k^3 \gt 2k+1$? which is clearly true $\forall k \gt 1, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Here is an alternative without induction. To prove $n!> n^2$ it's sufficient proving $(n-1)(n-2)>n$ or $(n-2)^2>2$ which is clearly true for $n\ge 4$. :)

Comment: You down have to use MathJax (TeX) to get italics.
See [markdown help](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#italics-bold). (Also when editing you have buttons for bold and italics - and also for help - at the top of your editor. Keyboard shortcuts are shown in tooltips when you hover with your mouse above these buttons.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be 100% vigorous with the proof, you'd need to show that $k^3 > 2k +1$ for $k>4$. And since it's an easy one, go ahead and do it with induction again.

Otherwise, you're 100% spot on with your induction. Note that you don't need to use strong induction. Weak induction would suffice. It only needs to hold for $k$ into order to prove $k+1$. But that would not make your proof any more correct, just more concise.

Well done. :)

Comment: ok; so then to show that $n^3 \gt 2n+1, \forall n\ge4$ first we show that this is true for $n=4$ which leads to $64 \gt 9$ which is true.  so then we assume this is then true for $n \le k$ and the induction step is to show that $(k+1)^3=k^3+3k^2+3k+1=(2k+1)+3k^2+3k+1=(2k+1)+(3k+2)(k+1)\gt(2k+3)$ thus $n^3\gt 2n+1\  \forall\ k \ge 4$

Comment: @user74091 Correct. That completed the proof entirely. Congrats! :)

Comment: oh good! thanks for saying so!